# How to assign the output of a command to an environment variable?

Tags: batch-file

I want to assign the value of a command run to an environment variable.
Google results gave me this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('command') do set Value=%%a
```

I tried the above to print the value of a particular command line argument that I need:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set argument_Count=0
set /A RUNCOUNT=1 
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('call echo %%!argument_Count!')     
do set Value=%%a
echo %Value%
```

But it doesn't seem to work. It is printing position rather than the argument value.

How can I get the argument value and set the variable?

Comment: Command `call` is for running another batch file from within a batch file. Command `echo` is not a batch file, but an internal command of `cmd.exe` like `call`.  Why do you not simply use `set "Value=%argument_Count%"` as all you want here is assigning the value of one environment variable to another environment variable. Hint: Open a command prompt window and run following commands: `set /?` and `call /?` and `for /?` and read the help pages output in the console window.

Comment: @mofi :  `set "Value=%set "Value=%argument_Count%` will give me the value as 0 but what i am trying to get is the **0**th command line arguement. And argument_Count is dynamic. i have just mentioned as 0 for simplicity

Comment: If you want the name and path of the batch file (argument 0) assigned to an environment variable use `set "Value=%~0"` as explained in help of command `call` on second page output in a command prompt window after entering `call /?` and executing this command with key RETURN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an Answer in another thread. writing the return value of command to a temp file and then reading it.

```
set REPORTfilename=%TEMP%/%random%.txt
call echo %%!argument_Count! >%REPORTfilename%
set /p REPORT=<%REPORTfilename% 
echo " REPORT " %REPORT%
```